# Fast calculation of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

- I was wondering how can i find $n$-th Fibonacci number using the recurrence equation

  $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$
- if starting $a$,$b$ is given some different random number say $a=5$,$b=8$ than $c=a+b$
- than it follows $5,8,13,21,34$.
- After googling, I came to know about Binet's formula but it is not appropriate 
  for values of $n>79$. And also it's for Fibonacci series starting from $0,1,1,2$ so on.
- Is there way to calculate it fast like a mathematical formula.
- [Edit] I tried using computer to calculate using dynamic programming, but it is taking long for say $n=2000000$.

Comment: Dynamic programming is the way to go. I don't know what you want if you think it's too slow. It's super fast. I just wrote a quick script and quickly computed n=10000

Comment: Binet formula is definitely approprioate for $n >79$. If you have troubles with that, it is probably because you get numbers which are way too big, and then nothing else can help.

Comment: @N.S. I'm pretty sure dynamic programming is probably faster, but yea, Binet's shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry I wrote n=10000 i meant big number like if n=4000000

Comment: See the last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binet's formula is fine for any $n$.  If it overflows on your computer, you need to have some way to handle large numbers.  Python switches over to arbitrary precision integers automatically.

If you use different starting numbers, the constants multiplying $\phi^n$ and $\psi^n$ change, but the basic formula does not.  Your formula will be $a\phi^n+b\psi^n$ and you can evaluate $a,b$ from your starting numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Given $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$, you can "double" the index by using the formulas $$\begin{cases}
F_{2n}=F_{n}(2F_{n + 1} - F_{n}) \\
F_{2n + 1} =F_{n}^2 + F_{n + 1}^2.
\end{cases}$$
More details can be find here: [Fast doubling](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms).